# How do I include the shipping and billing address when creating a Shopify order through the API?

Tags: shopify

I posted a question on the Shopify forums, but figured it would hit more eyeballs here: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/POSTing-to-orders-json-not-saving-billing-address-or-shipping/m-p/488324

We have a 3rd party system that creates orders in Shopify through the Shopify API. We're able to successfully create the order, but the Shipping address and Billing address never show up on the order even though they're supplied according to the API.

This is the payload we're sending:

```
{  
  billing_address:{  
     address1:'123 Main Street',
     address2:'',
     city:'London',
     province:'Ontario',
     country:'Canada',
     zip:'N6G 4B2',
     province_code:'ON',
     country_code:'CA',
     country_name:'Canada',
     phone:'555-555-5555'
  },
  customer:{
     first_name:'John',
     last_name:'Doe',
     email:'john@doe.ca',
     addresses:[
        [  
           {
            address1:'123 Main Street',
            address2:'',
            city:'London',
            province:'Ontario',
            country:'Canada',
            zip:'N6G 4B2',
            province_code:'ON',
            country_code:'CA',
            country_name:'Canada',
            phone:'555-555-5555'
           }
        ]
     ]
  },
  fulfillment_status:null,
  inventory_behaviour:'decrement_ignoring_policy',
  financial_status:'paid',
  line_items:[  
     {  
        variant_id: 94902079324,
        quantity: 1,
        price: '0.00'
     }
  ],
  shipping_address:{  
    address1:'123 Main Street',
    address2:'',
    city:'London',
    province:'Ontario',
    country:'Canada',
    zip:'N6G 4B2',
    province_code:'ON',
    country_code:'CA',
    country_name:'Canada',
    phone:'555-555-5555'
  }
}
```

The address supplied in the example is not a valid address, but our actual data has valid addresses.

This is what we see in the admin:

[image]

Comment: Hey @somethingOn did you find out any solution for this?

Comment: No I still haven't yet. I've tried a number of things since originally posting as you can see in my Shopify community post. #frustrating!

Comment: I was able to create the shipping_address but no luck with billing_address. I was missing the city in shipping_address, by adding the correct city It worked. You can try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me for `shipping_address` but wasn't able to create the `billing_address`. You can try this:

```
{
   "Order" : {
     #all other attributes,

    "shipping_address": {
      "first_name": "Jane",
      "last_name": "Smith",
      "address1": "123 Fake Street",
      "phone": "777-777-7777",
      "city": "Fakecity",
      "province": "Ontario",
      "country": "Canada",
      "zip": "K2P 1L4"
     }
   }
}
```

After spending alot of time I found out that `City` is required for `shipping_address` to show up there. Try tweaking the `city` attribute and check.

Comment: Holy crap it worked! I think it was my omission of `first_name` and `last_name` on the `shipping_address` that was the problem. THANK YOU Talha!!

Comment: Happy to hear that!! Is billing_address also working?

Comment: No, Billing Address doesn't show up. I think that might be related to the order being set to like order status being `fulfilled` or not having a `transaction` property on the order. I've read something elsewhere about why Billing Address may not show up on the Order admin.